# Learning Java arrays

Tags: java, arrays, string

I'm learning Java and I thought I maybe create a simple table using arrays. Not sure if the word "table" really refers to another Java topic that I'm not aware yet but be patient with me. I'm trying to make something like this

```
Country     Capital
Mexico      DF
Guatemala   Guatemala City
El Salvador El Salvador
Russia      Moscow
```

It took me some time to figure how to loop in the arrays and get the values, but I'm not really able to display the format above. You the experts have a good idea for this newbie?

I appreciate your patience and help.

```java
public class Arrays39 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String[][] countries = new String[4][2];
        countries[0][0] = "Mexico";
        countries[0][1] = "DF";
        countries[1][0] = "Guatemala";
        countries[1][1] = "Guatemala City";
        countries[2][0] = "EL Salvador";
        countries[2][1] = "El Salvador";
        countries[3][0] = "Rusia";
        countries[3][1] = "Moscow";
        System.out.println("Country " + "Capital");
        for (int i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                System.out.println(countries[i][j]);
            }           
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `.print` inside inner loop and empty `.println` right after inner loop

Comment: What does this print out? How does it differ from what you want? You are probably getting `"Mexico"` and `"DF` on separate lines, but want them on the same line. So the next step is to figure out why they are on separate lines. Then figure out what you can do differently so that they are printed on the same line.

Comment: Okay, so the code doesn't do what you want - **what is your question** about the result? What **does** it do, and **how is that different** from what you want? What do you think **needs to be changed** in order to get the desired result? Think carefully about these things, and then formulate a specific **question** about them, [check for duplicates](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/) and finally ask.

Comment: I get that this is a learning exercise. FYI, this is not a good use of arrays. Arrays are meant to store lists of data. Each element in the list should represent the same kind of thing. However, your inner array has two different kinds of things: a country and a city. For this situation a class would be appropriate to store the country and its capital. Then you can make an array of instances of this class.

Comment: This is probably a lot to take in right now. The short of it is that I recommend that you learn about classes soon. This will make a lot more sense when you do.

Comment: As a refresher, please read [ask] and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**. "You the Experts have a good idea for this newbie?" is [not actually a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236), but a request for unspecified help, which we do not provide here; and it is a sympathy plea that we [do not care about](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/422594) because your level of experience [is not relevant for us to understand a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343721) and does not change what the answer is.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way I thought of to create a table manually. One thing to consider is how you would solve the spacing issue for the table to display columns evenly. You can implement a solution for this problem by calculating a default max padding which will be the largest word in the first column. Then you have to add extra padding for word lengths smaller than the max in the left column. So you add the extra padding by calculating max word length - current word length in your for-loop condition.

It's great a idea to separate your logic into helper functions, so that you can take care of one task at time to solve the problem as a whole; jamming everything into the main method is not the right approach. If you have any questions, please feel free to ask.

```
public class Arrays39 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
          String[][] countries = {
             {"Mexico"      , "DF"},
             {"Guatemala"   , "Guatemala City"},
             {"El Salvador" , "El Salvador"},
             {"Russia"      , "Moscow"},
          };
          generateTable(countries, maxPadding(countries));
    }

      /* Prints out 2d-array */
      public static void generateTable(String[][] countries, int padding) {
         System.out.printf("Country %s Capital\n", addPadding("       ", padding));
         for(String[] country : countries) {
            System.out.printf("%s %s %s%n", country[0], addPadding(country[0], padding), country[1]);
         }
      }
      /* Two helper methods that find the max padding and the other calculates current word length to max padding */
      /* Generates padding from the country with the longest name */
      private static int maxPadding(String[][] s) {
         int max = 0;
         for(int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
            if(s[i][0].length() > max) max = s[i][0].length();
         }
         return max;
      }
      /* Formats each country name's padding based off the result of generatePadding() */
      private static String addPadding(String country, int padding) {
         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
         for(int i = 0; i < padding - country.length(); i++) {
            sb.append(" ");
         }
         return sb.toString();
      }
}
```

Output:

```
Country      Capital
Mexico       DF
Guatemala    Guatemala City
EL Salvador  El Salvador
Rusia        Moscow
```

Answer (score 0):

Use method [printf](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)) rather than method `println` or method `print`.

In order to display as a table, you need to first know the longest country name. In the below code, the first `for` loop does that.

```java
public class Arrays39 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String[][] countries = new String[4][2];
        countries[0][0] = "Mexico";
        countries[0][1] = "DF";
        countries[1][0] = "Guatemala";
        countries[1][1] = "Guatemala City";
        countries[2][0] = "EL Salvador";
        countries[2][1] = "El Salvador";
        countries[3][0] = "Rusia";
        countries[3][1] = "Moscow";
        int max = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
            int len = countries[i][0].length();
            if (len > max) {
                max = len;
            }
        }
        System.out.printf("%-" + max + "s  Capital%n", "Country");
        for (int i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%-" + max + "s  %s%n", countries[i][0], countries[i][1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Running above code produces following output:

```
Country      Capital
Mexico       DF
Guatemala    Guatemala City
EL Salvador  El Salvador
Rusia        Moscow
```